# How to fit listview inside constraint layout which has max height limit?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want the layout to be visible based on the content till max 80% of the device height.
Listview which is inside the constraint layout needs to fit (with scroll) between the above text and below button.

Problem:
ListView is overlapping with the above and below views.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:text="@string/error_try_again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="Please read the instructions below and try again to get accurate results"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instruction_list"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:text="@string/instruction_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instruction_subtitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Draw TextView1 (instruction_title) at the top of parent, then draw TextView 2 (instruction_subtitle) below TextView1 (top_toBottomOf).

Then draw Button at the bottom of parent.

Finally draw ListView top_toBottomOf TextView 2 (instruction_subtitle) and bottom_toTopOf Button (error_instruction_again) and set height of listview to 0dp to make sure that ListView will expand all height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"
        android:id="@+id/guideLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideLine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:text="instruction_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:text="Please read the instructions below and try again to get accurate results"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/instruction_title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button_highlight"
            android:text="error_try_again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instruction_subtitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The list is consuming extra space below when it has one item row. How can we avoid those extra spaces? How can we wrap according to content if max height < 0.8? when I try to add this `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"` at parent, list is not visible

Comment: I think we can not use app:layout_constraintHeight_max for constrain layout when there is listview inside it.  Please try to add another constraint layout, and make it as parent of 2 textviews, buttons and listview and it will be the child of the constraint layout that its heigt is 0.8 percent of screen.  And add the height of this constrain layout will be set to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues from what I can see, one is the chaining: when you want to order elements with a constraint layout you have to define both the top and bottom relationship for everything (or start and end if you're stacking them horizontally).

For example your `instruction_subtitle` is missing the top constraint. You can read about chains [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain). You can add them automatically selecting elements in the component tree of the design view, right clicking them and choosing chains -> create/modify existing chains. For small layouts like this you can simply write them.

Another thing about chaining, if you want your widgets layout to be stretched according to the constraints, you need to use 0dp for the `layout_width` or `layout_height`. Change your list `layout_height` to 0dp.

After that, remove `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"` from your contraintlayout

Some notes:

- you can use  `tools:listitem="@layout/your_list_item_layout"` to show a preview of your items in the list
- why use a listview instead of a recyclerview?
- Keep your widget in the same order as they appear on the screen, you have button - list - text - text but what you need is text - text - list - button

Final code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
            android:text="@string/instruction_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instruction_subtitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="Please read the instructions below and try again to get accurate results"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instruction_list"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instruction_title" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/instruction_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instruction_subtitle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/error_instruction_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:text="@string/error_try_again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instruction_list" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The list is consuming extra space below when it has one item row. How can we avoid those extra space?

Comment: How can we wrap based on content? Do we need to control the parent or list?

Comment: It's not resolved yet. Let me know if any fix can help!

Comment: I understand what you want to do but I' m not sure how it's doable. At the moment you' re trying to implement two behavious in one: if the list is big make it fill as much space as possible and show a button on the bottom of the layout, if the list is small wrap it around the items and show the button on the bottom of the list. I'd honestly just leave the button on the bottom since you're also  gonna have a lot of wasted space below it if you don't. You can try to play with app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" to make the list respect the max height parameter